# VMware workstation 6.5 VMs (Host-only network with static ip address) cannot ping each other

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, ping, vmware-workstation

I had specified Host-only network and disabled the dhcp server that comes with the Host-only network.

I had setup the following network config,

*vm1*
ip address: 192.168.147.2
netmask: 255.255.255.0
no default gateway

*vm2*
ip address: 192.168.147.3
netmask: 255.255.255.0
no default gateway

From VMware workstation documentation, my Host-only network is set to 192.168.147.0.

With the above, I tried to ping between each VMs but can't.

Appreciate any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Host-only network will not work, because this means you can only ping yourself.

What you can do is create a new VMnet and put both VM's in that VMnet. In this way you should be able to let them ping eachother

Answer (score 0):

when you use host only option it means the VM can only ping the host machine and not other vm
if you want it to ping each other you need to change the settings